# pipe awk output into c program

Tags: c, awk, terminal, pipe

Hi I have written a c program that takes 3 integers as input:

```
./myprogram 1 2 3
```

and I am aiming to pipe data from a csv file into the input of the c program. I grab each line from the c program using:

```
for i in $(seq 1 `wc -l "test.csv" | awk '{print $1}'`); do sed -n $i'p' "test.csv"; done;
```

and then would like to pipe the output of this into my c program. I have tried doing:

```
for i in $(seq 1 `wc -l "test.csv" | awk '{print $1}'`); do sed -n $i'p' "test.csv"; done; | ./myprogram
```

however I get:

```
Line 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

how do I pipe the output into my c program?

Thanks

Comment: Change `done; |` to `done |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, it doesn't like an explicit line termination followed by a pipe (`|`). The pipe already delimits the commands. So you want:

```
for i in $(seq 1 `wc -l "test.csv" | awk '{print $1}'`); do sed -n $i'p' "test.csv"; done | ./myprogram
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps when you really try to understand error messages the shell gives you:

```
Line 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

If you think about it, when you chain commands together in a pipeline, there is never a `;` before a `|`, for example:

```
ls | wc -l
# and not: ls; | wc -l
```

Whatever comes after a `;` is like an independent new command, as if you typed it on a completely new, clear command line. If you type `| hello` on a clear command line, you'll get the exact same error, because that's the exact same situation as `; | ...` in your script, for example:

```
$ | hello
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Others already answered this, but I also wanted to urge you to make other improvements in your script:

1. Always use `$()` instead of backticks, for example:

   ```
   for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -l "test.csv" | awk '{print $1}')); ...
   ```
2. You didn't need the `awk` there, this would work just as well:

   ```
   for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -l "test.csv")); ...
   ```
3. You could reduce your entire script to simply this, for the same effect:

   ```
   ./myprogram < test.csv
   ```

Comment: Good detail (+1). Mine was the "lazy answer". ;)

Comment: @mbratch yours was fair enough, normally I don't go this far, but poor scripts really disturb me, and I was just in the mood... Thanks for the vote, I appreciate it!